# ASP.Net / ASP.Net MVC-- request contents of one page from another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jsonp

I have to write a page method in ASP.Net that returns a JSONP result.  In order to build its payload for return however, it has to read a URL from another domain, passing it some parameters that were passed to it originally.

I suppose I'll need to screen scrape the results to see if the login credentials worked.  Could point me toward ideas that might begood for ASP.Net or ASP.Net MVC?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by opening a hidden iframe and traversing the DOM

Comment: Thanks.  What .net classes are best suited to reading a page these days-- a WebClient, perhaps?  I'm a little rusty in this area.

Comment: I would do this client-side using javascript.  That way you can validate before submitting to the server.